# How to get the drive letter of pendrive

Tags: mfc, winapi, visual-c++

I want to get the drive letter of pendrive or external harddisk connected through USB.
Is it possible to get the Drive letter. I am using VC++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GetLogicalDriveStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975(v=VS.85).aspx) lists all existing drive letters and [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939(v=VS.85).aspx) can determine whether the drive is removable. `GetDriveType` help suggests using `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` to make sure the drive is USB one.